# Unable to use style on other UI composables aside Text

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I can use:

```
Text(
    ...........
     style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
     .........
   )
```

But I cant use:

```
 ClickableText(
    ...........
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2. //not working
)
```

I need to use the `'style'` attribute for text related UI composables like `ClickableText` and while building annotated strings using `withStyle(...)`

Also I should be able to call my theme - `Materialtheme.typography.whatever` on the style

Comment: Note that according to [TextDelegate](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/TextDelegate.kt;l=58) if you want to use both withStyle() on AnnotatedString and the style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2. The AnnotatedString style will always have the higher priority. Means withStyle() will always take priority over the passed style attribute on ClickableText.

Comment: I cant even pass 'style' attribute to ClickableText

Comment: You can pass the style attribute, can you post your entire code so that I can have a look?